# Firebase SetDisplayName Without signing In

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

What im trying to accomplish is just letting the user create a user by email/password then apply a Displayname to the newly generated user. The only issue is i cant apply a display name to the new user without first logging the first one out. Im somewhat new to firebase so maybe there is something i missed. Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,

Firebase google have implemented some new mechanism called as a RULES, when you go in your Firebase dashbord select database from left slide bar and then select `RULES` from right, Here is the default rules which define you can not access database without authentication means (login), So change your rules with following condition and publish it then after it work fine,

Just replace your rules with following,

```
{
  "rules": {
         ".read": "auth != null || auth ==null",
            ".write": "auth != null || auth ==null"
  }
}
```

Comment: if your rules are by default which set by google then its not permitted to do changes on database without authentication , But if you have change rules which i given then it permit to change data for both type of user authenticated or unauthenticated,

Comment: right the rules that you posted allow unauthenticated users to read and write correct?

Comment: yes, Because you have declared as without login so its require,

Comment: i want to only allow authenticated users to read and write what im asking is if i can set the displayname of a user during or after i create it with the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method while staying signed into the user curently signed in

Comment: I dont understanding what you want to say in comment but if you want to change displayname after login Below code may be help you 


UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder builder=new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder();
                builder.setDisplayName("User Name");

Comment: i want to sign into a user create a user and change the new users displayname without signing into the new user or if possible create the new user sign into the new user change the displayname then sign back into the old user but i dont want the user of the app to have to sign in again after creating a new user

Comment: Hi, Sorry but I cant understand your comment because you written so complex, You can write it step by step,

Comment: Ok first is it possible to sign in then create a user then without signing out change the display name of the new user?

Comment: `".write": "auth != null || auth ==null"` is the same as `".write": true`. So the rules you have in this answer give everyone in the world full access to your database. While it may solve the problem at hand, it is probably not what you want.

Comment: Could I just save all this login information on firebase and retrieve it when needed or would someone be able to steal that from the realtime database even if authorization is required